# How to insert one column from a table into another based on a join/where clause

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have two tables, temp_am and amphibian. The relationship between the two tables comes from the lake_id and the survey_date column in both tables. Both tables have 24,109 entries.

temp_am

| id | lake_id | survey_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10,001 | 7/25/2001 |
| 5 | 10,005 | 7/27/2001 |
| 6 | 10,006 | 7/29/2001 |

etc...

amphibain

| id | lake_id | survey_date | amhibian_survey_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10,002 | 7/25/2001 |  |
| 2 | 10,005 | 7/27/2001 |  |

etc...

I want to input the temp_am.id into the amphibian.amphibian_survey_id when both lake_ids and survey dates equal each other.

I have tried this sql query but it never worked. I canceled the query after 600 seconds as I figured a 29,000 observation table should not take that long. Please let me know if you see any issues in my query statement.

```
update amphibian 
set amphibian_survey_id = tm.id 
from amphibian a
inner join temp_am tm 
on a.lake_id = tm.lake_id 
and a.survey_date = tm.survey_date
```

This query worked in microsoft access but not on DBeaver

```
UPDATE amphibian 
inner JOIN amphibian_survey_meta_data md ON 
(amphibian.survey_date = md.survey_date) AND (amphibian.lake_id = md.lake_id) SET amphibian.amphibian_survey_id = [md.id];
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgres does not require repeating the table name for an *update join*. In this case even the join is not necessary just  `set <column> = ( select ... )` is sufficient. See [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a16439a8c7ccaba0d9da99e8ee44983d).

```
update amphibain a  
   set amhibian_survey_id = 
       ( select tm.id 
           from temp_am tm 
         where (tm.lake_id, tm.survey_date) = 
               (a.lake_id,  a.survey_date)
       ) ;
```

Comment: when I run the query I get this error. "SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression"

Comment: I got the query to work. It seems my subset prior was not correct for the temp table. So I used the initial meta data table. Thank you for the help